# How to disable a part of concept check for boost::wave?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor

I know that there is a problem in boost such that concept check will not pass for boost::wave. However I want as thorough a concept check as possible. Is there any way to JUST turn off concept check for boost::wave, but keep everything else? i.e. is there a macro like one would use with `/#pragma pop_macro("MACRO")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [The Boost Concept Check Library (BCCL)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)
which can provide you with help to resolve your issue.